# Asp.net and data with multiple users

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5

I'm building a website for an internal project that kind of emulate a [SCADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA).

The client log in, and is presented with a visual situation of a plant, the data needed to make everything work is either stored in a DB or directly taken from a PLC via modbus or other protocols.

The question is:

Can I have something on the webserver (in this case IIS 7.5) that pools the data, let's say every 5 second, and make it available to my application, so I do not have every client open a connection but only 1 connection is needed ? Is it possible ?

If something is unclear let me know and I'll try to elaborate further.

Comment: You should probably look at caching as a solution. Each request to the web server can look in the cache to see if the data has already been loaded and, if not, go to the database to get it. The cache can have an expiry date so that after five minutes it become invalid and the next request will go get fresh data.

Comment: Problem is that I need something much faster, the data needs to be updated every 5-10 sec at most. That's why I wanted something on the webserver end and not on the client end that update the data. The client just need to look at the data in memory(if it's even possible) and do something with that data without worrying.